# How to pass a script to a Windows 8 Vagrant box from the Mac command line?

Tags: windows, macos, shell, vagrant, command-line-arguments

I'm running a Windows 8.1 guest on a Mac OSX 10.11 host, via Vagrant.  I want to pass in a script to this guest via command-line.  If the guest were Unix-based, I could just do `vagrant ssh -c "$THE_SCRIPT" my-unix-box` and call it a day.  When I try for the Windows guest, I'm told that the command `bash` does not exist.

However, I can `vagrant ssh` into the Windows guest without specifying a command just fine.  The resulting shell is `cmd`, **not** PowerShell or Bash or similar.

**How can I execute a script on a guest Windows Vagrant box (from an OS X host) by passing it in on the command line?**  Vagrantfile configuration, guest software to install, or similar.  I'm not picky about which shell ultimately runs my script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you can pass the script to `vagrant` with double-dash separation, like so:

```
WINDOWS_THINGS="..."

vagrant ssh windowsBox -- "$WINDOWS_THINGS"
```

In my case, this will run the contents of `WINDOWS_THINGS` as a `cmd` script.  I guess the interpreter used depends on the underlying box, but whatever the case this solved my problem.  Someone on IRC suggested this to me, and unfortunately I don't remember their name.  But, if you're reading this, thank you!